# ValueError: embedded null character for flaskenv on windwos with dotenv

Tags: python, windows, flask, dotenv

I am trying to use flask dotenv along with python-dotenv but I noticed that there is an inssue on Windwos 10.

Everyting works fine on Mac,Linux but on windows when I run the flask application I get an exception.

It seams that the issue is with the file `.flaskenv`. If I rename the file from `.flaskenv` to `_flaskenv` there is no exception anymore but my env variables are not defined. I have tried to also to load manually this file but without any success. the `_flaskenv` is not loaded.

```
# .flaskenv
FLASK_APP=manage.py
FLASK_ENV=development
```

````
PS D:\practice\flask-dotenv> flask run
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\popam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Users\popam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "D:\practice\flask-dotenv\venv\Scripts\flask.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "d:\practice\flask-dotenv\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 894, in main
    cli.main(args=args, prog_name=name)
  File "d:\practice\flask-dotenv\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 548, in main
    load_dotenv()
  File "d:\practice\flask-dotenv\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 608, in load_dotenv
    dotenv.load_dotenv(path)
  File "d:\practice\flask-dotenv\venv\lib\site-packages\dotenv\main.py", line 309, in load_dotenv
    return DotEnv(f, verbose=verbose).set_as_environment_variables(override=override)
  File "d:\practice\flask-dotenv\venv\lib\site-packages\dotenv\main.py", line 138, in set_as_environment_variables
    os.environ[k] = v
  File "C:\Users\popam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\os.py", line 684, in __setitem__
    self.putenv(key, value)
ValueError: embedded null character```
````

Comment: The message basically says it all -- the value of the variable contains embedded NULL character (`\0`). Can you host the actual file somewhere so we can take a look?

Comment: Here are all the files: https://github.com/ppmadalin/flask-dotenv.git